# How can I resolve loading of xml2json in my electron app

Tags: node.js, electron

I am starting a new Electron app, working with VScode on Windows 10. I am starting to write the code and the first step is to load an XML file into a JSON object so that my app can process the data in the XML file.

I have installed xml2json (v0.11.2) with some warnings but no errors reported. I have the required xml2json at the beginning of the file in which it is needed. When I try to run my app with the VSCode debugger I get an exception when the xml2json module is required.

```
const xml2json = require ('xml2json') ;
```

The exception says:

```
Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\c:\DataRoot\Projects\DevicePackProcessor\node_modules\node-expat\build\Release\node_expat.node
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:166:20)
```

How can I resolve this problem please?
Sid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

electron version ?

you need to rebuild that module according to electron's node version !!!

use electron-rebuild  https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild

Comment: Electron v4.0.0. I don't understand how to "build that module according to electron's node version"